# MySQL select records from specified timeframe

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on creating a leaderboard for my game and I have the following PHP function that selects data from my database and orders it by score and the WHERE statement restricts it to the month

```
public function getTopMonthMobileUsersByPoints() {
    try {
        $query = "select
                        u.id 
                        ,u.name
                        ,u.email
                        ,u.password
                        ,u.facebook_id
                        ,u.created_date
                        ,u.token_uid
                        ,sum(s.total_points) as earned_points
                        ,u.used_points
                        ,u.gender
                        ,u.birthdate
                        ,0 AS ranking
                from 
                    mobile_user u
                    join score s on s.mobile_user_id = u.id
                where
                    year(report_date) = year(now()) and
                    month(report_date) = month(now()) and 
                group by
                    u.id
                having
                    sum(s.total_points) > 0
                order by 
                    sum(s.total_points) desc
                limit 100 ";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'class\Model\MobileUser');
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->logger->error("PDO: ".$e->getMessage(), ["class"=>get_class($this),"method"=>__METHOD__]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to include a similar function that does basically the same but where the mysql selects records from a given timeframe, for example from June 2018 to August 2018.

Is there a way i can tell mysql to select records from the future? Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Normally for a MySQL date comparison, you can just provide a string timestamp conditional:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] [JOINS] WHERE report_date >= "2018-06-01" AND report_date < "2018-09-01"
```

You can pass the dates as string as parameters and just use the variables withing the query. Don't forget the quotes though; all strings need to be encapsulated by a string delimiter.

Comment: `report_date >= '2018-06-01' AND report_date < '2018-09-01'` should work fine, because a date is equivalent to its timestamp at midnight.